Unity Photon join room issue
i'm learning unity photon multiplayer and i need your help with,
Player 1 creates room and is sitting in room lobby, Player 2 starts game or is in main menu, enters join room scene, but cannot see any rooms created,
But..
if player 2 is already in join room scene, then player 1 creates room, now player 2 sees room instantly and can join that room, very bizarre, have been trying to figure it out since 3 days, i tried creating all together new scroll view, new button prefabs, even changed script 3 to 4 times depending on which youtube tutorial says what to write, please help,
below is code for creating room,
public TMP_InputField input_Create;

public void CreateRoom()
{
    if (input_Create.text.Length >= 2)  // Ensure valid room name
    {
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(input_Create.text, new RoomOptions() { MaxPlayers = 
6, IsVisible = true, IsOpen = true }, TypedLobby.Default, null);
    }
} 

Below is script for getting roomList,
public class RoomList : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
public GameObject RoomPrefab;
public GameObject[] AllRooms;

public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
{
    // Destroy any previous rooms
    for (int i = 0; i < AllRooms.Length; i++)
    {
        if (AllRooms[i] != null)
        {
            Destroy(AllRooms[i]);
        }
    }

    // Initialize the array of rooms
    AllRooms = new GameObject[roomList.Count];

    // Create new rooms based on the list received
    for (int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (roomList[i].IsOpen && roomList[i].IsVisible && roomList[i].PlayerCount >= 
1)
        {
            GameObject Room = Instantiate(RoomPrefab, Vector3.zero, 
Quaternion.identity, GameObject.Find("Content").transform);

            // Access Room component and set room details
            RoomLegacy roomComponent = Room.GetComponent<RoomLegacy>();
            roomComponent.Name.text = roomList[i].Name + " (" + 
roomList[i].PlayerCount + "/" + roomList[i].MaxPlayers + ")";
            roomComponent.actualRoomName = roomList[i].Name;  // Store the actual 
room name for joining

            AllRooms[i] = Room;
        }
    }
}
}

there is a room button prefab which has code to join room,
public TMP_Text Name;  // UI element to display room name
public string actualRoomName;  // Store the actual room name to join

public void JoinRoom()
{
    // Ensure the client is ready and connected before joining
    if (PhotonNetwork.IsConnectedAndReady && PhotonNetwork.InLobby)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(actualRoomName);  // Use the actual room name for 
joining
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Client is not ready.");
    }
}

please help.
